# Supervisord events only sent to one eventlistener in pool

Tags: linux, supervisord

I am using the [Event](http://supervisord.org/events.html) protocol in superervisord to send a 'TICK' event to each of my processes every X number of seconds. The problem is that I want a pool of these processes to be run (`numprocs`=4), and for each process to receive the signal. What I am seeing is that only one process actually receives the TICK signal, and the others receive nothing.

I have stripped the problem down to a simple python script. This script takes a single argument that is used to generate a file name for a log file. In the log file, the signals are recorded. I would expect that if I launch 4 of these scripts using supervisord then I would get 4 log files which grow over time. Instead I get one file which grows. Here is the python script, `event.py`:

```
import sys


def write_stdout(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()

def write(name):
    with open(name, 'a') as f:
        f.write("signal\n")

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        name = "%s.txt" % sys.argv[1]
    else:
        name ="0.txt"

    while 1:
        write_stdout('READY\n') # transition from ACKNOWLEDGED to READY
        line = sys.stdin.readline()  # read header line from stdin
        write_stderr(line) # print it out to stderr
        write(name)
        headers = dict([ x.split(':') for x in line.split() ])
        data = sys.stdin.read(int(headers['len'])) # read the event payload
        write_stderr(data) # print the event payload to stderr
        write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK') # transition from READY to ACKNOWLEDGED

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    import sys
```

And here is how I am configuring the supervisord eventlistener:

```
[eventlistener:test]
numprocs=4
process_name=test-300%(process_num)02d
command=python /home/blah/event.py 300%(process_num)02d
directory=/home/blah
events=TICK_5
stopsignal=INT
stopwaitsecs=15
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Here are the logs from supervisord:

```
$:) sudo tail -n500 /var/log/supervisor/*
==> /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log <==
2014-12-29 16:45:12,752 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-12-29 16:45:12,752 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor-vpserver.conf" during parsing
2014-12-29 16:45:12,755 TRAC 127.0.0.1:Medusa (V1.12) started at Mon Dec 29 16:45:12 2014
    Hostname: localhost
    Port:9001
2014-12-29 16:45:12,785 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-12-29 16:45:12,786 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-12-29 16:45:12,786 TRAC /var/run/supervisor.sock:Medusa (V1.12) started at Mon Dec 29 16:45:12 2014
    Hostname: <unix domain socket>
    Port:/var/run/supervisor.sock
2014-12-29 16:45:12,786 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-12-29 16:45:12,786 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-12-29 16:45:12,787 BLAT supervisord forked; parent exiting
2014-12-29 16:45:12,787 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2014-12-29 16:45:12,788 INFO supervisord started with pid 15766
2014-12-29 16:45:13,791 INFO spawned: 'test-30002' with pid 15775
2014-12-29 16:45:13,793 INFO spawned: 'test-30003' with pid 15776
2014-12-29 16:45:13,795 INFO spawned: 'test-30000' with pid 15777
2014-12-29 16:45:13,798 INFO spawned: 'test-30001' with pid 15778
2014-12-29 16:45:13,817 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918461240 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:13,818 DEBG 'test-30002' stdout output:
READY

2014-12-29 16:45:13,818 DEBG test-30002: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:13,819 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918531512 for <Subprocess at 140274918760528 with name test-30003 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:13,819 DEBG 'test-30003' stdout output:
READY

2014-12-29 16:45:13,819 DEBG test-30003: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:13,829 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918532088 for <Subprocess at 140274918706928 with name test-30000 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:13,829 DEBG 'test-30000' stdout output:
READY

2014-12-29 16:45:13,829 DEBG test-30000: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:13,829 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918532664 for <Subprocess at 140274918707072 with name test-30001 in state STARTING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:13,829 DEBG 'test-30001' stdout output:
READY

2014-12-29 16:45:13,829 DEBG test-30001: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:14,830 INFO success: test-30002 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-12-29 16:45:14,830 INFO success: test-30003 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-12-29 16:45:14,831 INFO success: test-30000 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-12-29 16:45:14,831 INFO success: test-30001 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-12-29 16:45:16,833 DEBG event 0 sent to listener test-30002
2014-12-29 16:45:16,833 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918461240 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:16,833 DEBG 'test-30002' stdout output:
RESULT 2
OKREADY

2014-12-29 16:45:16,833 DEBG test-30002: BUSY -> ACKNOWLEDGED (processed)
2014-12-29 16:45:16,833 DEBG test-30002: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:16,834 BLAT read event caused by <POutputDispatcher at 140274918461384 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
2014-12-29 16:45:16,834 DEBG 'test-30002' stderr output:
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:0 pool:test poolserial:0 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871515
2014-12-29 16:45:21,839 DEBG event 1 sent to listener test-30002
2014-12-29 16:45:21,839 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918461240 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:21,840 DEBG 'test-30002' stdout output:
RESULT 2
OKREADY

2014-12-29 16:45:21,840 DEBG test-30002: BUSY -> ACKNOWLEDGED (processed)
2014-12-29 16:45:21,840 DEBG test-30002: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:21,840 BLAT read event caused by <POutputDispatcher at 140274918461384 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
2014-12-29 16:45:21,840 DEBG 'test-30002' stderr output:
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:1 pool:test poolserial:1 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871520
2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 DEBG event 2 sent to listener test-30002
2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918461240 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 DEBG 'test-30002' stdout output:
RESULT 2
OKREADY

2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 DEBG test-30002: BUSY -> ACKNOWLEDGED (processed)
2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 DEBG test-30002: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 BLAT read event caused by <POutputDispatcher at 140274918461384 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
2014-12-29 16:45:26,846 DEBG 'test-30002' stderr output:
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:2 pool:test poolserial:2 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871525
2014-12-29 16:45:31,852 DEBG event 3 sent to listener test-30002
2014-12-29 16:45:31,852 BLAT read event caused by <PEventListenerDispatcher at 140274918461240 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stdout)>
2014-12-29 16:45:31,853 DEBG 'test-30002' stdout output:
RESULT 2
OKREADY

2014-12-29 16:45:31,853 DEBG test-30002: BUSY -> ACKNOWLEDGED (processed)
2014-12-29 16:45:31,853 DEBG test-30002: ACKNOWLEDGED -> READY
2014-12-29 16:45:31,853 BLAT read event caused by <POutputDispatcher at 140274918461384 for <Subprocess at 140274918707144 with name test-30002 in state RUNNING> (stderr)>
2014-12-29 16:45:31,853 DEBG 'test-30002' stderr output:
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:3 pool:test poolserial:3 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871530

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30000-stderr---supervisor-NystkJ.log <==

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30000-stdout---supervisor-h4mTFE.log <==
READY

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30001-stderr---supervisor-zJJKe7.log <==

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30001-stdout---supervisor-936BaW.log <==
READY

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30002-stderr---supervisor-NXzezy.log <==
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:0 pool:test poolserial:0 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871515ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:1 pool:test poolserial:1 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871520ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:2 pool:test poolserial:2 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871525ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:3 pool:test poolserial:3 eventname:TICK_5 len:15
when:1419871530
==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30002-stdout---supervisor-K_tGpa.log <==
READY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY
RESULT 2
OKREADY

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30003-stderr---supervisor-mOXclj.log <==

==> /var/log/supervisor/test-30003-stdout---supervisor-6Q521a.log <==
READY
```

It looks to me like `test-30002` is the first of the 4 processes to spawn (lowest PID), and therefore it is the one to receive the events. All of the others get left out. Is this known behaviour when using an `eventlistener` group and `numprocs` > 1?

UPDATE:

I should probably also add this:

```
$:) supervisord --version
3.0b2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine to me, as noted [here](http://supervisord.org/events.html#configuring-an-event-listener) and described in more detail [here](http://supervisord.org/events.html#event-listener-notification-protocol), only one process in the pool is supposed to get each event and it can be any process that is `READY`.

As you are seeing, supervisord just finds the first one in the pool that is not busy. As long as the processing of a `TICK_5` event takes less than 5 seconds that would always be first process.

Comment: Thanks. I missed this part "One of the listeners in each listener pool will receive the event notification (any “available” listener)."